# mySQL DataSource on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, datasource

I've been reading about mySQL DataSource and the ability to use mySQL with Entity Framework, but I can't really generate EF with mySQL without the use of the DataSource Dialog

[image]

How can I add mySQL Database to such dialog?

This is what I have done so far:

- Installed [mySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) v.6.5.4
- Restarted n-times my Windows 7 machine
- Read all about how well mySQL Connector works on previous versions of Visual Studio

Comment: I posted the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806294/mysql-connector-for-visual-studio-2012-update-3/19760429#19760429

Comment: @pafivi that is now as they have an installer, my question was asked back in October last year (2012) where no installer was available, database was still 5.3.x and connector version was 6.5.4, where's [today is 6.7.4](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) but thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you are trying to get VS2013 connected, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20589057/1002222

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have just read from mySQL Forums that mySQL will ship Visual Studio 2012 integration with mySQL Connector v.6.5.5

> We'll be adding support for VS 2012 in Connector/NET 6.5.5 and later 6.6.x version
>   http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,564533#msg-564533

and give a link to test a trick

> http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/10476.instalando-mysql-connector-no-visual-studio-2011-beta.aspx

and here is the `vsix` file if you follow [the tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/10476.instalando-mysql-connector-no-visual-studio-2011-beta.aspx) (In Portuguese)

> **Microsoft Visual Studio Extension** for mySQL: http://cl.ly/JqXO

just **download and double click**...

then, you will get all to work

[image]

*Using Visual Studio 2012 Professional*

[image]

Comment: balexandre your extention doesn't seem to work anylonger. Maybe it's the VS2012 Update 3 that just came out or the new 6.7.4 MySQL .NET connector that just released. After reinstalling your extention MySQL appears in the datasource list and I can test my credentials but when I click "OK" Visual Studio throws an error and doesn't let me add the connection.

Comment: I am having the exact issue described by Jeremy Sheldon. The same behavior occurs whether I use the vsix linked above (seems to be for an older version than the latest), and when I use the MySQL web installer to get the Visual Studio MySQL Connector/NET 1.0.2. Not only does clicking OK throw the "unable to find requested .NET Framework Data Provider," but entering any text in the form for Server Name, User Name, or Password results in the form being immediately closed. This is described (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-6-7.html) as being fixed, but...

Comment: Hello balexandre do you have this kind of file for latest version of mySql 6.7.4.0 ?

Comment: for `6.7.x+` mySql installs it along the full product: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html it includes "MySQL for Visual Studio"

Comment: Please use the official extension, http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/ (which supports VS2008 / VS2010 / VS2012 / VS2013)

Answer (score 7):

One clarification: Visual Studio Express DOES NOT support MySQL .NET Connector as extension.

You still may use it adding reference to MySql.Data.dll file that you may find in MySQL Connector installation folder (for me it was W:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector NET 6.5.4\Assemblies\v4.0).
After that you may use it like this:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...
var mycon = new MySqlConnection();
```

Comment: the idea is to be able to use mySQL in the Server Explorer, for that, you need the extension I mention on my answer!

Answer (score 5):

According to this page: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

"Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows (see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html)."

Comment: true, just installed yesterday on a brand new machine with windows 8 :)

Comment: almost knocked my head off trying to figure how come v6.7 does not appear on Visual Studio Data Source list. ended up installing the whole package (mysql-installer-community-5.6.13.1.msi - 192MB !)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2012 is not yet supported by `MySQL Connector v.6.5.4`. You can't add a connection to MySQL in the Server Explorer to begin with.

According on this [post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,564533#msg-564533), support will be added on `MySQL Connector v.6.5.5`

Comment: thxs, with your pointer added my own question with the Extension to download and works lovely.

Answer (score 1):

Connector/NET 6.5.5 does not support VS2012, but Connector/NEt 6.6.x does.

However Visual Studio Express editions are not supported, hence the only way to work in Entity Framework and Visual Studio Express and MySql (or other database different than SQL Server for that matter) is using code first.

Comment: Remember that you are duplicating an answer (my own), as I do state that since 6.5.5 it will be supported. But the question was made in **October 2012**, where the last version was only **2.5.4** (without native support for VS)

Comment: Not exactly, the post http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,564533#msg-564533 is wrong, VS2012 is not supported in 6.5.x (any 6.5) but is supported in 6.6.

Comment: It's not supported out of the box, but if you download, install and run the extension I provided in my answer, work's as a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't matter if you had the MySQL driver showing as far as I can tell. I'm running VS 2012.3 and if I try to create a Data Connection in VS Server Browser, I can get as far as selecting the MySQL driver and no more. If I try typing a servername/username/password (any of the fields), the window just disappears and YES, it's only when the MySQL driver is being used so NO it's not vs (not exclusively) causing the problem. Go ahead and say that it's my environment but you'd not be able to justify that even remotely compared to the FACT of what is happening. ALL my other software/extentions/add-in/libraries work just fine. No surprise either seeing how buggy the "3 minute" Windows Installer was. Had to uninstall/reinstall a server instance to get to the configuration wizard and there is no other apparent way to configure an instance without it. I'd rather have the old setup. /rant

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded and install Download MySQL for Visual Studio http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.1.html