# How to configure mysql with asp.net Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to connect MySQL database with entity framework from vs2010-12(Web developer).

I have downloaded and installed MySQLConnector(**MySQL-connector-net-6.6.5.msi**) to connect with entity  framework.

After installation I have created a new website,added a entity data model and tried to configure but in the **Entity Data Model Wizard** I am not able to see the data source of MySQL to configure it with my database.

Anybody have idea on this.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Download this : http://cl.ly/JqXO

Kindly refer to this answer : [mySQL DataSource on Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012)