# MySQL connector in vs 2012 express

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, connector

Is there any workaround? Express does not support extensions, what should I do in order to use connector?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Project| Add Reference|C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 6.6.5\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Data.dll

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Tag = "Server=MY-PC;Database=myDB;User Id=" & TextBoxUID.Text & ";Password=" & TextBoxPWD.Text & ";Connection Timeout=20"
        Try
            Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(Me.Tag.ToString)
            connection.Open()
            connection.Close()
            MsgBox("Connection is okay.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```