# MySQL with VisualStudio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and I have to establish a connection to an MySQL-Database.

I read the following thread:
[mySQL DataSource on Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012)

The solution "is working"...respectively I am able to see "MySQL Database" as a possible DataSource 
After I clicked the button "Continue", I have to enter the Server name, User name and passwort.

Now my problem:

If I only type or copy one character the new window closes without any error message or reason... I've tried to find a solution on this and different plattforms, but I couldn't find one...

I would be grateful for help

Kind regards

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use MySQL over MS SQL Express or another MS solution?

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow.com, so I am not allowed to upload pictures.

Second question: I have to use MySQL, I would also prefer MS SQL Server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an idea, so I tried to use the On-Screen Keyboard... And with this it is possible to insert the required data like server name, user name and so an... Stupid solution but it works and I just habe to insert the date once...