# MySQL Database Connection With Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, connector, visual-studio-2013

I was using Visual Studio 2013 Preview but I couldn't find MySQL database in the "choose data source" dialog window, I even installed the latest version of MySQL connector as well as the windows MySQL installer (to get MySQL plugin for visual studio) but nothing changed, I had to get back to VS 2012 Ultimate, I just wanted to know if there is a special MySQL connector for the 2013 Preview Edition?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and I got it working with the Mysql Visual Studio 1.1.1 beta plugin.

Requirements:

- Windows OS 7 or later.
- Visual Studio 2010, 2012 or 2013 professional or higher version.
- Connector/Net **6.8.1 beta or higher version** to check the Connector/Net & Entity Framework features. (download at: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ on the development releases).

Download:

https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi

**You can find the latest here (v1.2.3):**

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

Source:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601041,601041#msg-601041

Comment: Do I need to restart the PC after install this.Because it's not work for me.

Comment: @Ren [Mysql Visual Studio 1.1.4](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,609530) has been released. Try with that version.

Comment: Always look for newest version... :-) [search here](http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/MySQL/Downloads/MySQL-for-VisualStudio/). currently, latest version name is `mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.3.msi`

Answer (score 4):

I use Visual Studio 2012. 
Correct process of installing MySql will help you avoid any such error. At least this is what i did.

1. Download and install visual studio 2012
2. Download and install mysql-installer-community-5.6.17.0
3. Download and install mysql-connector-net-6.8.3
4. Download and install mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1
5. Order is important and each item too.
6. Open Visual Studio and Create new project
7. Add reference of MySql.Data in solution explorer after right clicking the project name
8. View server explorer
9. Add new connection and fill the spaces correctly
10. At the top of your code, add using MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Comment: .. Thank's a lot , i'll keep that in mind next time i'll use Visual Studio with mysql

Answer (score 2):

For Visual studio 2013, install "MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8"

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested it yet, and it's for VS2012 (and I guess it's the same for VS2013) but the following link may help:

http://blog.nwoolls.com/2012/07/25/registering-missing-data-providers-with-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: .... I had to go with sql server after all , but thank's for the help anyway , that was very useful .