# Not Able to Select MySQL from Choose Data Source In Visual Studio 2013

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, linq-to-entities

I am trying to use Linq-to-Entity and connect with my local mysql database. 
But, when i select the mySql at the Choose Data Source Part. I hit the error as below:

[image]

> An error occurred that is normally caused by not having for Visual
>   Studio properly installed.

But I did install > Uninstall > re-install Visual Studio 20143 again. The error still come out. 
I also have try to Install like the below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589057/1034986

also not work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql-for-visualstudio-xx.xx, if installed, then uninstall may solve the problem.

Comment: site:https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/