# MySql data source and MySQL project template not appearing in Visual Studio 2013 community edition

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, plugins, visual-studio-2013

***I wanted to use MySQL from Visual studio 2013 community edition***

For this -

- I have installed Visual studio 2013 community edition which can be used as a host for connecting to MySQL as per [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/you_can_use_mysql_for) blog.
- I (re-) installed [MySQL for Visual studio plugin](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_for_visual_studio_12)

[image: MySQL for VS]

- I (re-) installed [.NET connector for MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

[image: .NET connector for MySql]

- I (re-) started my machine twice.

But still I cannot see the MySQL data source and data provider in *Choose data source* dialogue of Visual studio 2013.

[image: MySQL data source and data provider not appearing]

Is there any manual configuration which is required?

**UPDATE**: The solution I accepted also helped me to make MySQL project templates appear in Visual Studio 2013 Community IDE.

I tried the following *similar* (not-duplicate) questions:

[It's about VS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012)

[Asked about generic data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455893/visual-studio-2013-project-add-new-data-source-not-available)

[This is applicable for Express versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio)

[MySQL data source is appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751658/not-able-to-select-mysql-from-choose-data-source-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: Dunno how to say this to You but... it works for me with no configuration. I've only installed from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/ and chose .MSI (was installing with VS turned off). And installed that now specially for You to check.

Comment: However, I recall I have very fresh installation of VS Community 2013 (it has like 3 days). Maybe there was something fixed in recent patches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" and check the versions of the following files,

- MySql.Data.dll
- MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
- MySql.Web.dll

Compare them to the files found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.6\Assemblies\v4.5", if they are not the same, try and replace them with files found here.

Some people have had better luck using older versions of these assemblies, try using 6.9.5 assemblies.

Alternatively add referencees to these files directly into your project.

Ensure you have the following in your app.config;

```
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Glad I could help, which step resolved the issue for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Data provider' drop down filter, you have '.Net Fr... For SQL Server', you need to select '.Net Fr... For MySQL'.

If you can't see that option, can you provide a screenshot of the existing filters?