# The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2013, mysql-error-1064

so I'm making a project and I'm almost done with it and this error got me, I thought in the 1st place my database is not connected but it's connected and I don't really know what is the solution for it(correct me if I'm wrong in the problem that I gave.)and im using a visual studio 2013

I have done reconnecting my database by checking and unchecking it but still doesn't work[this is the error that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3dIz.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should need to add a .dll to the Reference section in the Solution Explorer (from GAC or browse for file).

Comment: "MySql.data.dll" like this? in the references section?

Comment: Yes. File name may depend of the provider you use and you have installed. https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: in the reference section, I can't put it in but what i did is  'add reference, brows section, brows then i add the "MySql.data.dll" and checkt it.
but still dosent work

Comment: What provider do you use? How do you install it? Is it a x32 or x64 or anycpu version? What platform do you target? Can you do a screenshot of the solution explorer?

Comment: I downloaded the lower ver. of "mysql" the 6.9.12 and I install it but when I run my visual studio there is no "mysqldata" in the extension section

Comment: Downloaded from where?

Comment: btw I install the obdc  Mysql connector and I don't know what reference that I'm going to add
-libea32.dll
-myodbc8a.dll
-myodbc8S.dll
-myodbc8w.dll
-ssleay23.dll

Comment: In the solution explorer on section References, right click and choose Add reference. Then in tab Assemblys, search MySql.Data or System.Data.MySql or a thing like that and check it. Then click OK. It should work. If you can't find the assembly namespace, find it on the drive where it was installed and add it in tab Browse.

Comment: If you installed an odbc driver, you can use "using System.Data.Odbc;" and create an ODBC alias.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package MySql.Data

```
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data
```

for more check this question: [MySql doesn't work in Visual Studio 2012 : The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787270/mysql-doesnt-work-in-visual-studio-2012-the-type-or-namespace-name-mysql-co)