# The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2013, mysql-error-1064

so I'm making a project and this error that I got.and I really don't know how to solve it I add "Myslq.data.dll" in the reference and check it but still doesn't work.

I tried to check and un-checking the"Mysql.data.dll" and reconnecting my database still doesn't word
[image: some errors and warnings]

[image: i have dont adding the "Mysql.data.dll"]

Comment: Please modify the question to show the EXACT error message that you're getting.  If it's in a message box and  you can't copy it, use the Snipping Tool to snip an image of the message box, and post that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836838/the-type-or-namespace-name-mysqlconnection-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing)

Comment: If you need to stick with .NET 4.5.2, MySqlConnector https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ is an alternative MySQL ADO.NET library that supports that framework version.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I see the problem.

Your first image shows an error message at the bottom. It indicates that the version of MySql you're using is LATER than the version of .NET you're using.

You need to look at your project properties, at the *target version* of the assembly you're building, and adjust it to match the version of MySql.

But, it's possible that VS 2013 (which you said you were using) can't work with that late a version of .NET, because it came out *after* VS 2013 did.  In that case, you'll have to find an earlier version of the MySql assembly to use.

If that's the case, I would go look on the MySql home page, and see if they have a link for earlier versions of MySql.

You would need a version of that assembly that is compatible with **.NET Framework v4.5**.

Comment: I downloaded the lower ver. of "mysql" the 6.9.12 and I install it but when I run my visual studio there is no "mysqldata" in the extension section

Comment: You could also switch to MySqlConnector https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ which is compatible with .NET 4.5.