# Visual studio 2013 Ultimate MySQL DataSource

Tags: c#, mysql, datasource, visual-studio-2013

I've been working on a project that is connected to a MySQL Database, and i had this question: is it much more efficient to have your project connected to a "Datasource"?

If so:

I've been trying to add one, but I'm not getting this option:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/images/connector-net-visual-studio-choose-data-source.png

What is causing this?

Ive got my MySQL Connecter/NET installed, and I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Using MySQL with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate is kind of an anachronism.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012

Comment: That does not work for me..

Comment: I've the same problem - some solutions here allready?

Comment: [Here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601041,601041#msg-601041) is the beta version of MySql for Visual Studio that includes support for VS2013. Links at the bottom of the post.

Comment: You can use VS2012 to do what you need an after this just open project in VS2013. It will work.

Comment: Just install this and will be ok http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601041,601041#msg-601041