# Database Migrations in VS2012(MVC 4) from default SQL Express LocalDb)v11.0 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, database-migration

I am currently facing a issue of how to migrate the database for user information which is created by default in VS 2012. When I create a project, a LocalDb\v11.0 is created with all user tables and database.

In my application I want to use MySQL as database. I am able to run, connect and access MySQL database running on MySQL workbench. But I am facing this issue of how to migrate User Access Controls i.e, Account Controllers and Home Controller are already given; Currently when I press on Login I am redirected to a page to enter my login credentials. Which uses this default SQL Express LocalDb.

I want to use the code functionality which is provided to me by Microsoft but want to use a MySQL database.

I am currently thinking of migrating from default SQL db in which Account/user tables are, to MySQL and then operate code with MySQL database. There is no specific post which targets this issue. I am really clueless now, can someone give some pointers as of where to start?

```
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ImageRepository-20140121114624;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ImageRepository-20140121114624.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am thinking of making this Default Connection to point to mySQL Db that I have but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to modify your connection string to connect to your mysql database.

you will find more info here

[mySQL DataSource on Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012)

if you are using entity framework in your project it will be compatible with mysql.

Comment: Hello Matt, I am able to add a connection string with MySQL database that I have created in my machine. Issue is I want to use the already created Account/User control features which are provided to me. When make a new project and replace the default connection string to one I have created it starts saying that there is some error with the connection string. I can also tell you the specifics of the error.